# .htaccess: Redirecting x.com/sub/ to y.com/sub/

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect people visiting x.com/sub to y.com/sub/

This .htaccess in the *sub*-Folder gives me an *ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.y.com/sub/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Does anyone know, how the correct rule should look like and where I need to put it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `RewriteCond` to check for original host:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(?:x|v|w)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.y.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```

Test it from a new browser to avoid old cache.

Comment: Perfect, many thanks!
Do you know the rule, if I want to add other domains (v.com, w.com), that also redirect to y.com?

Comment: This seems to be redirecting me to *https://www.y.com{request_uri}/*
The error in Firefox ist "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN"

Comment: Yes, but it redirects me to a URL {request_uri} - so it doesn't translate to the real request uri :)

Comment: I see, sorry for the wrong formatting!
It redirects me to `https://www.y.com{request_uri}` instead of `https://www.y.com/blog/some-url`

Comment: Thank you for helping patiently! It is now redirecting to `https://www.y.de/blog%7BREQUEST_URI%7D`

Comment: Sorry there was typo. Try it now in new browser.

Comment: YES! Working now, many thanks (I had to remove the `/blog` though :)